# Can't retrieve MathID

Tags: installation

I stopped using *Mathematica* for some months. In the meantime, I received a "your activation key has been extended" e-mail. Since I didn't run it, *Mathematica* went *inactive* (i.e., I need to activate it). I need to use it again.

My problem is, I need to generate a password, but in order to do that, I first need my *MathID*, which, seemingly, I can only retrieve once *Mathematica* is active (I can only get to the *activate mathematica* screen, which prompts for a password), or (maybe) by reinstalling.

Here is a screenshot of the prompted window:

[image]

Is there a way to retrieve my *MathID* while *Mathematica* is not activated?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is more of a question for WRI support... anyway, the screen asking for a password should show a button like "other ways to activate" or such, which will display the `MathID` at some point.

Comment: It doesn't :( I whish I could attach a screenshot...

Comment: I should've known, shame on me http://i.imgur.com/YL4JCrJ.png

Comment: I think this issue should be addressed to WRI indeed. I doubt anyone here can help you more than that.

Comment: By WRI you mean Wolfram's support, right?

Comment: Yes indeed, you should send them an email :)

Comment: If you have a WolframID account, you can also log in and chat with WRI support - that was very convenient last time I had license issues.

Comment: FTR, I e-mailed them and they told me mine was a lab version, which uses a special (lab-specific) MathID. I installed the right version and everything worked as expected. Thanks you too, @YvesKlett

Comment: Click "Other Ways to Activate", then in the screen "Select a method to activate", choose "Manual activation". The Math ID should then appear, above a field to type your activation key and a field to type your password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other than via the regular dialog displayed at startup, you should be able to retrive your `MathID` from your "mathpass" file. On my system (Windows 7) it can be found here:

C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Mathematica\Licensing

This file contains machine name, MathID, activation key and the password.

Comment: The folder is empty (!). I also browsed for the Local-equivalent, but there was no Licensing folder

Comment: @Öskå true, but without MMA running, evaluating `$UserBaseDirectory` will be problematic ;-)

Comment: @Rafael can you search for "mathpass" on your machine? Perhaps it is mislaid...

Comment: Ok. I found a mathpass at C:\ProgramData\Mathematica\Licensing, but it has a 24 digit (hex consistent) number that won't work. Neither does a 14-digit suffix (the actual MathID is supposed to have the form 1234-12345-12345)